# How to get the highest values from 2 columns in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, vba

I have a design software which extracts data in to an Excel sheet format
The output is divided into 2 columns, each of these columns has more than 1000 rows. 
To make use of this data I need to summarize it to a maximum of the 5 highest values from both of the 2 columns. Therefore, this doesn't mean that it's the maximum of one column and its corresponding value, but it may mean that the 2nd largest value of column 1 & the 4th largest value of column 2.

For example ( if we quoted some of the output data):

[image]

The values i should pick here are:

[image]

If there is any possible way to achieve that, it will be great

Thanks ..

example file: http://goo.gl/UIEFEv

**example file 2**: http://goo.gl/VSvuVf

Comment: use max() on each column and than a vlookup to get the corresponding value from the other column

Comment: the max value of each column doesn't mean it's the max from the other column, so it won't work.

Comment: Have you considered using a pivot table and set a filter of top x (x = any value you want). This will display the top values and hide the rest for you.

Comment: use a vlookup formula with a rank() formula. I think any way you go about this you will need to use an array formula anyway

Comment: Petay: i tried pivot tables, but i couldn't match the top 5 results using it

Comment: S O : i dont get what u mean by rank formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a formula solution. I used 20 rows and extracted the rows which contain the top 5 for each column - you can extend to as many rows as required.

With data in A1:B20 use this formula in D1 confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied across to E1 and down both columns:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$20,SMALL(IF(($A$1:$A$20>=LARGE($A$1:$A$20,5))+($B$1:$B$20>=LARGE($B$1:$B$20,5)),ROW(A$1:A$20)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(D$1:D1))),"")`

Note: there are only eight rows extracted because some of the rows contain values in the top 5 for both columns. I added the highlighting in colums A and B to more clearly illustrate

see screenshot below

[image]

**Edit:**

From the comments below it seems that you want a combination of rows which contain the highest value for that column....and rows which contain the highest **total** for **both** columns.

In the original formula there are two conditions joined with "+", i.e.

`($A$1:$A$20>=LARGE($A$1:$A$20,5))+($B$1:$B$20>=LARGE($B$1:$B$20,5)`

The "+" gives you an `"OR"` type functionality, e.g. in this case rows are included if individual values are in the top 5 in that particular column. You can add other conditions, so if you want to also add any rows which are in the top 5 considering the total of both columns then you can add another "clause", i.e.

($A$1:$A$20>=LARGE($A$1:$A$20,5))+($B$1:$B$20>=LARGE($B$1:$B$20,5)**+($A$1:$A$20+$B$1:$B$20>=LARGE($A$1:$A$20+$B$1:$B$20,5))**

....and including that in the complete formula you get this version:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$20,SMALL(IF(($A$1:$A$20>=LARGE($A$1:$A$20,5))+($B$1:$B$20>=LARGE($B$1:$B$20,5))+($A$1:$A$20+$B$1:$B$20>=LARGE($A$1:$A$20+$B$1:$B$20,5)),ROW(A$1:A$20)-ROW(A$1)+1),ROWS(D$1:D1))),"")`

You could refine that further by using combinations of `+` and `*` (for `AND`), e.g. for the new condition you might only want to include rows with a total in the top 5 if one of the single values is in the top 10 for that column...

**Explanation:**

The above part shows how you can use `+` for the `OR` conditions. In the formula if those conditions are `TRUE` then the `IF` function returns the "relative row number" of the range (using `ROW(A$1:A$20)-ROW(A$1)+1`).

SMALL function then extracts the kth smallest value, k being defined by ROWS(D$1:D1) which starts at 1 in D1 (or E1) and increments by 1 each row.

`INDEX` function then takes the actual value from that row.

When you run out of qualifying rows `SMALL` function will return a `#NUM!` error which `IFERROR` here converts to a blank

Comment: thanks alot .., it's working great, but can you please explain the equation more, because i got confused in the second line of it

Comment: i was testing it in another example but an error occured, it gets the critical values, but one , there was one with high values in both columns, but not the maximum in any of them , so it was skipped , so is there a way to get over this ..

Comment: @user3151946 I'll add some explanation to my answer. I can't re-create your error - can you give an exact example? As you can see from my example the formula should happily pick up rows where there top five values in both columns

Comment: please check example 2 updated above, the results at the right, don't include the critical value No. 2930, please check

Comment: If you drag the formula down a few more rows you will see 11 rows populated for that example (there are 6 for column A because there's a tie for 5th place). The results are as I would expect, perhaps I haven't entirely understood the requirement. By "No. 2930" do you mean row 2930? I don't see why that row would be included

Comment: yeah i meant row No. 2930, the results on it is "446" for column A & "410" for column B, which are higher values & not included on the results at the right

Comment: OK, I thought the idea was to pick the rows with the 5 highest (individual) values in each column - A2930 is the 213th highest value in column A and B2930 is the 342nd highest value in column B so neither qualifies by my criteria - is it the **sum** of the values, even there A2930+B2930 is only the 11th highest sum, should row 2929 be included, that's actually the highest combined total of any of the rows?

Comment: OK, but I don't understand the criteria for inclusion now. In your original example you included the row with 100, presumably because 100 is the largest value in column A, but the combined total of that row is only 456, so it wouldn't be included if the criterion was the row **total**. Are you saying that you want to show rows which have the largest single values in the column **and also** rows which are in the top n when totalled. If so how many of each? which rows would you include in example 2?

Comment: sorry for my late reply, yeah that's what i meant, i need to get the rows with the highest values  either separately or in total, as i described before the values in rows no. 2929 & 2930 are high, but it didn't get it, the error also that i can't sole is that if we have column a let's say has a value of 20.001 & it's correspondent value is 0.001 & another value in column a is just 20 & it's correspondent is 5, excel will pick 20.001 where the 2nd case is more critical , i understand this mathematically, but i don't know how to get over it in excel. , thnx 4 ur effort

Comment: OK, the formula can be amended to give you a combination of rows which have the highest **individual** values....and rows which have the highest **combined** totals - I edited my answer to show how that can be done, and also added some explanation of the formulas

Comment: thanks alot for your time & your explanation .., it's working  v well now

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little unclear but if what you mean is to get the 5 highest values of Column A and their corresponding values in Column B then the five highest values in Column B and the corresponding values in Column A then the (non automated) solution is pretty simple.

1. Click on a cell with a header title in it.
2. Click on 'Data' in the top menu.
3. Click on 'Filter' in the 'Sort & Filter' section.
4. Click on the button on Column A - select 'Sort Largest to Smallest'
5. Grab the top five values from both columns then click on the button in column B and repeat.

Comment: This way will work only if i have few output data, but imagine iam talking about more than 1000 output 7 i have to repeat this many times , so if for every time i repeat these steps, it will take too much time, what i want is kind  of match between the 2 columns to check the highest in the first column, if the corresponding value is high then ok , if not then take the second value & check its correspondent & so on...

Comment: Try it out, I use these kinds of tools for looking at files hundreds of thousands rows long. If the data set is REALLY big you should look into managing it in a database instead of excel.

If you are talking about many instances of 1000 rows of information then we probably need some more information about how this is structured.

Comment: please check the updated reply above first, i tried it already but it will be very hectic to repeat it every time & also this is counting on my observation for the values which i may mistake for a time because of the much of the data ..

Comment: example file attached