# Create a Dynamic Array formula (Excel) to combine multiple results columns into one column that is filtered & sorted using multiple criteria?

Tags: sorting, excel-formula, filtering, dynamic-arrays, sumproduct

The sample data in the image below is collected from a round robin tournament.

[image]

There is a Round column,Home team & Away team columns listing who is playing who. A team could be either Home or Away.

For each match in a round (including any "Bye" match) the number of games won for the Home and Away team are recorded in separate columns respectively.
"Ff" = forfeit and has a value of 0. "Bye" result is left blank (at this stage).

Output columns are "Won, Lost, Round".

**Required output** (shown in the image) is, for any selected team, the top n most-games-won matches (from both Home & Away) sorted in **descending** order and then the corresponding games lost but sorted in **ascending** order where the games won are equal. Finally show the rounds where those scores occurred.

These are the challenges I've faced in going from data to output in one step using dynamic array formula:

1. Collating/Combining the the Win results into 1 column. Likewise the Losses.
2. Getting the array to ignore blanks or convert "Ff" to 0 without getting #NUM or #VALUE errors.
3. Ensuring that if I used separate single column arrays the corresponding Loss and Round matched the Win result
4. Although "Round, Won, Lost" would be acceptable. But I wasn't able to get the Dynamic Array capability to give the required output with this order.

SUMPRODUCT, INDEX(MATCH), SORT(FILTER) functions all hint at a possible *one step formula solution*.

The solutions are numerous for sorting & filtering where the existing values are already in one column. There was one solution that dealt with 2 columns of values which was somewhat useful [How to get the highest values from 2 columns in excel - Stackoverflow 2013](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27600053/how-to-get-the-highest-values-from-2-columns-in-excel)
Many other responses are around the use of concatenation, combining/merging array sets, aggregation etc.

My work around solution is to use a Helper Sheet to combine the Wins from the separate results columns and convert blanks & "Ff" to -1. Likewise for Losses. Using the formula for each line
=IF($C5=L$2,IF($F5="",-1,IF($F5="Ff",0,$F5)),IF($D5=L$2,IF($G5="",-1,IF($G5="Ff",0,$G5)),-1))

[Example Helper Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da5eT.png)

To get the final output the Dynamic Array formula was used on the Helper Sheet data
=SORT(FILTER(L$26:N$40,L$26:L$40>=LARGE(L$26:L$40,$J$3),""),{1,2},{-1,1},FALSE)

I'm trying to avoid using pivottable, VBA solutions. Powerquery possible but not preferred.

Apologies for the screenshots but I couldn't work out how to attach the sample spreadsheet file. (Unfortunately Stackoverflow Help didn't help me to/not to do this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments I changed my answer with a different approach:

```
=LET(data,A5:F19,
     round,INDEX(data,,1),
     ha,CHOOSECOLS(data,3,4),
     HAwonR,CHOOSECOLS(data,5,6,1),
     w,BYROW(ha,LAMBDA(h,IFERROR(XMATCH(L2,h),0))),
     clm,CHOOSE(w,{1,2},{2,1}),
     srtwon,DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,INDEX(HAwonR,z,HSTACK(INDEX(clm,z,),3))))),1),
     res,FILTER(srtwon,w),
TAKE(SORT(res,{1,2},{-1,1}),J3))
```

Old answer:

```
=LET(data,A5:F19,
     round,INDEX(data,,1),
     home,INDEX(data,,3),
     away,INDEX(data,,4),
     HAwonR,CHOOSECOLS(data,5,6,1),
     w,MAP(home,away,LAMBDA(h,a,OR(h=L2,a=L2))),
     won,FILTER(HAwonR,w),
TAKE(SORT(won,{1,2},{-1,1}),J3))
```

[image]

In your example you selected round 3 for the third result, but that wasn't won, so I guess that was by mistake.

As you can see making use of `LET` avoids helpers. `Let` allows you to create names (helpers) that are stored and because you can name them, you can make complex formulas be more readable.
Basically what it does is filter the columns Home, Away and Round (in that order) for either Home or Away equal the team in cell `L2`. That's sorted column 1 descending and column 2 ascending. Than the number of rows mentioned in cell `J3` are displayed from that sorted array.

Comment: Thank you @P.b. That was 4 functions that I had not considered using or using in that way.

Comment: (Sorry hit the enter key which posted)
Re Round 3: the Away Team = Team#2 and they defeated Home Team = #4, 2 games to 0 games respectively. 
Therefore this result needs to be included in the top 3 for Team#2 because in this match they lost 0games compared with round 4 where they lost 2games.
To clarify: it doesn't matter if the team concerned won/drew/lost matches, it is the team's 3 best number of games won, from either Home or Away matches (with the corresponding games lost to break ties for games won). 
Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Gotcha, I changed my answer based on your comments. That required a different approach making use of XMATCH for finding the column the home team played in and using CHOOSE on it's result to define the indexing of data per row and REDUCE to do the indexing per row.

Comment: That was an even more challenging to decode but I got there. :-) Learnt a lot.
From what I can determine from your solution is that in the REDUCE function the accumulator result can be "an array". All the help pages I reviewed on this (including Microsoft's) don't give a real hint that an array is possible. Well done for proving otherwise.

Comment: I think this explains well how REDUCE works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75145553/12634230 (bottom part of post)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on the excellent contribution by @P.b. Thank you much appreciated.

The wins (likewise losses) required mapping the presence, of the team in question, as hT (home team) to the games it won (hG) and adding to that a 2nd mapping of the games it won (aG) when it was the away team (aT). Essentially what was being done on the Helper Sheet. Result was a 1 column array for game wins and a 1 column array for game losses.

In the process I was able to convert the "Ff" text to 0. I attempted without the conversion and it threw an error.

Instead of CHOOSECOLS used HSTACK to create the new array (wins, losses & round) for the FILTER, SORT, TAKE to work on.

If it could be made conciser(?) that is the next challenge. Overall (not just my solution), this exercise has provided greater flexibility and solved the problems stated. I'm happy!

```
=LET(data,A5:G19,
    round,INDEX(data,,1),
    hT,INDEX(data,,3),
    aT,INDEX(data,,4),
    hG,INDEX(data,,6),
    aG,INDEX(data,,7),
    wins,MAP(hG,
            MAP(hT,LAMBDA(h,h=L2)),
        LAMBDA(w,t,IF(w="Ff",0,w)*IF(t=TRUE,1,0)))  +
        MAP(aG,
            MAP(aT,LAMBDA(a,a=L2)),
        LAMBDA(w,t,IF(w="Ff",0,w)*IF(t=TRUE,1,0))),
    losses,MAP(aG,
            MAP(hT,LAMBDA(h,h=L2)),
        LAMBDA(w,t,IF(w="Ff",0,w)*IF(t=TRUE,1,0)))  +
        MAP(hG,
            MAP(aT,LAMBDA(a,a=L2)),
        LAMBDA(w,t,IF(w="Ff",0,w)*IF(t=TRUE,1,0))), 
    HAwonR,HSTACK(wins,losses,round),
    w,MAP(home,away,LAMBDA(h,a,OR(h=L2,a=L2))), 
    won,FILTER(HAwonR,w),
TAKE(SORT(won,{1,2},{-1,1}),J3))
```